# m4 preprocessor "ERROR: end of file in string"

Tags: 12.04, makefile

I'm getting this error msg:

```
m4:myPerlScript.pl:77: ERROR: end of file in string
```

when trying to use m4 to replace a string in some perl scripts. I'm making the call inside a makefile.

```
$(OUTDIR)/%:    %.pl
        m4 blah/thing.m4 $< > $@
        chmod +x $@
```

i made sure that thing.m4 exists and is in the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that m4 was erring because of its sensitivity to quotes. I added `changequote()` to the replacing .m4 file.

It was also necessary to use the -P switch to avoid matching m4 key words, and add m4_dnl to each line.

Answer (score 1):

To others who have made it here, OP's error may also present as the result of a missing closing square bracket (likely, any unpaired bracketing character).